# Unity 3: The type does not have an accessible constructor

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a following interface and implementation

```
namespace ProjectName.Web
{
    public interface IWebUtil
    {        
    }
}


namespace ProjectName.Web
{
    public class WebUtil : IWebUtil
    {                
    }
}
```

in my config i have this registration. I am using Unity 3.

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <assembly name="ProjectName.Web" />
  ...
   <register name="WebUtil" type="ProjectName.Web.IWebUtil" mapTo="ProjectName.Web.WebUtil">
     <lifetime type="transient" />    
   </register>
  ...
```

When I try to resolve this configuration I am getting this error:

```
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type IWebUtil does not have an accessible       constructor.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:
Resolving ProjectName.Web.IWebUtil,(none)
```

I have tried to add empty public constructor but no sucess.

Can anybody help with this? thanks.

Comment: Can you post your container creation and resolving code? Are you correctly loading the configuration with `IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
    .LoadConfiguration();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to ensure that you are loading the Unity configuration since this is not done by default.  To do this:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;

container.LoadConfiguration();
```

I'm assuming you've done this.  I'm also going to assume that you are trying to resolve IWebUtil using the following code:

```
container.Resolve<IWebUtil>();
```

This throws an InvalidOperationException because IWebUtil is configured as a named registration (with name "WebUtil").  So either resolve using the configured name:

```
container.Resolve<IWebUtil>("WebUtil");
```

Or change the registration to be a default (unnamed) registration:

```
<register name="" type="ProjectName.Web.IWebUtil" mapTo="ProjectName.Web.WebUtil">
 <lifetime type="transient" />    
</register>
```

Comment: the problem was, that i was calling resolve without parameter